# TestCafe failed to start a worker on browser (chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, browser-automation

I am trying to get TestCafe to work for a very simple test.  My operating system is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I have set up my browser as follows:
Browser Name: google-chrome-stable
Path: /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable

No command-line options.

I have also verified that chrome is at that location by doing an ls -lsa on the /usr/bin folder which gives me this:

0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          32 Jun 22 11:14 google-chrome-stable -> /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

So I see that it is a symlink with full permissions

My test fixture is this: http://orchestra.updatepromise (which is publicly available on the net) and I have set up the following test:

```
"@fixture test fixture";
"@page https://orchestra.updatepromise";

"@test"["log in"] = {
    '1.Type in input "username"': function() {
        var actionTarget = function() {
            return $("[name='form'].ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-invalid").find("[name='username']");
        };
        act.type(actionTarget, "dealer_admin");
    },
    '2.Type in password input "password"': function() {
        var actionTarget = function() {
            return $("[name='form'].ng-untouched.ng-invalid.ng-dirty").find("[name='password']");
        };
        act.type(actionTarget, "NopeNoPasswordHere");
    },
    '3.Click submit button "Log In"': function() {
        act.click(".btn.btn-primary");
    }
};
```

When I run this test. I get the following output:

Failed to start Task

Failed to start a worker on browser "google-chrome-stable". This may occur if the browser was closed before the worker initialization or due to browser hangup.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Addendum:

Also, I've been having another issue regarding chrome that may be related.  When I have chrome open with several tabs every once and a while the tabs and the header go all black and I can't select anything.  I looked into this and other people were having the same issue and they seemed to solve the problem by starting chrome from the command like like so:

google-chrome --use-gl=angle &

with this in mind, I added a new browser definition in testcafe which added the --use-gl=angle & to the command line options.  Unfortunately this one also failed with the same error

Comment: Would you please clarify what TestCafe version you are using? 
I've installed TestCafe 15.1.3 and Chrome 69.0.3497.100 (Official Built) (64-bit) on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and TestCafe automatically detected the Chrome browser. 
 
If you are using the same TestCafe version (15.1.x), try using the 'Find installed browsers' action in the Control Panel. 
Also, I recommend that you check out the newest Open Source TestCafe version and see how it works with Chrome. It supports outdated test syntax that is illustrated in your sample.
P.S. For some reason, your web site is not reachable on my side.